# Facebook API - Unreachable post but Reachable comments

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

**Setup**

I have a specific Public Facebook Status Post X on a Facebook Page.

```
I have the ID of the Post X (by checking the URL to Post X on Facebook itself  
https://www.facebook.com/{pageName}/posts/{postXid} )
```

I have an access token that has following scope permissions :

```
public_profile, basic_info, read_mailbox, read_page_mailboxes, 
read_insights, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_groups, user_friends
```

**Issue**

- I can NOT access Post X through GRAPH API OR FQL API.

  - When I try this, the API returns "Unsupported Get Request" (typical returned on deleted and hidden posts)
- I DO can access the COMMENTS on Post X through GRAPH API and FQL API.

  - FQL API (comments table) by using the PageExternalId_PostXId format for the post_id
  - GRAPH API by the ids I got from the FQL results
- The post and all comments are perfectly visible on the Facebook Page itself

  - When I check the privacy settings of the Post on Facebook itself, it says : "Shared With Public"

**The Problem**

Does anyone have an idea or experience why I can not access the post ? Privacy settings that I am not aware of or so ?

**N.B:**

I personally don't have admin rights to the Facebook Page, only access token. It can't be hidden or deleted because it is visible to EVERYONE.

**Extra Info after comment**

These are the queries I tried.

GRAPH

- ApiPoint/v1.0/postId -> Unsupported get request
- ApiPoint/v1.0/pageId_postId -> Unsupported get request
- ApiPoint/v1.0/postId_commentId -> Object returned
- ApiPoint/v2.0/postId -> Unsupported get request
- ApiPoint/v2.0/pageId_postId -> Unsupported get request
- ApiPoint/v2.0/postId_commentId -> Object returned

FQL

- SELECT id, text FROM  comment WHERE post_id = 'pageId_postId' -> Comment on the Post Returned
- SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 'pageId' -> Post not listed
- SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'pageId_postId' -> Empty result set
- SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'postId' -> Empty result set

Comment: What query did you use? Also, may you please give the post id so that we have enough information to clearly identify the problem?

Comment: I have added the queries I tried. The postId/url is https://www.facebook.com/norwegianfi/posts/882804465078804